# MediaElement in ElementHost Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, mediaelement, audio-player, elementhost

I'm trying to create a simple `MediaPlayer`, but I need to mute left/right audio channels, so I have to use `MediaElement`. I got the following error when I tried to add the player to the `ElementHost`:

> Error CS1503   Argument1: impossible to convert from
>
> 'System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement' to
>
> 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.

Here's the code:

```
ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement player = new System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement();
host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
host.Controls.Add(player);
```

Comment: @Makyen: Thanks, I'll remember that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to play audio, I would use MediaPlayer instead of MediaElement. It doesn't have a UI component.

If you still want to use MediaElement, set the child of ElementHost:

```
ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement player = new System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement();
host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
host.Child = player;
```